# how to start vmware from java

Tags: java, virtual-machine, vmware, vmware-workstation

I have written a java program that also needs to verify that my VMware workstation exists and should start up my VMware workstation if not already running. How should I do this? Currently I do the code below but I also need to start up a specific VMware workstation also.

```
public void runVM() throws IOException{
    File vmPath = new File("../VMware/VMware Workstation/vmware.exe");
    File iePath = new File("../Documents/Virtual Machines/InkEstimator_K2");
    if (vmPath.exists() && iePath.exists()){
        //check if running 
        Desktop dt = Desktop.getDesktop();
        if(vmPath.canExecute()){
            dt.open(vmPath);
        }
     }
}
```

Thanks, any advice is appreciated!

Comment: I would look on starting a `Process` from java, I advise you also see apache commons utils as they have tools to support processes creation

Comment: basically the idea is that as you in Windows cmd/Unix shell execute programs, you do exactly that but in java(for Windows you would execute `C:\Program Files\...\vmware.exe` but instead of cmd in java)